# Как правильно обработать OperationCanceledException при отмене операции?

Tags: c#, async-await, task

Я запускаю в отдельном потоке выполняться метод, в процессе выполнения которого возникает ситуация, когда нужно дождаться освобождения ресурса. В этом случае я запускаю ожидание через `Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, source.Token)`, который потом прервется из другого потока, но у меня возникла проблема. После того как другой поток прерывает ожидание, он застревает в бесконечном цикле метода, вместо того чтоб разблокировать поток и продолжить выполнение.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DelayInfinite
{
    class Program
    {
        private static CancellationTokenSource source;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Run(Work);

            Console.ReadKey();
            source.Cancel();

            Console.WriteLine("Press AnyKey to end");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static async void Work()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task.Delay(Infinite)");
                source = new CancellationTokenSource();
                await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, source.Token);
            }
            catch
            {
                // ignored
            }

            Console.WriteLine("WhileTrue");
            while (true)
            {
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

На данный момент я нашел два способа добиться того что я хочу:

1. В обработке исключения добавить `await Task.Delay(1);` - в этом случае прерывающий поток обрабатывает ошибку и продолжает свою работу, а заблокированный поток возобновляет свою работу.
2. При прерывании ожидания создавать новый поток `Task.Run(() => source.Cancel());` - в этом случае создается новый поток, который продолжает выполнение метода в отдельном потоке.

У меня возник вопрос, как правильно обработать эту ситуацию? Есть ли другие способы возобновить работу потока?
Текущие способы похожи на костыли, поэтому я ищу другие способы решить эту проблему.

UPD: Сделал еще один пример
Надеюсь по нему будет понятнее что я делаю.
При выполнении этого кода в консоль не выводится "End Work", потому что основной поток застревает в методе WorkAsync после отмены ожидания.

```
    class Program
    {
        private static CancellationTokenSource WaitResourceTokenSource;
        private static bool IsResourceAvailable = true;

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var workTask = Task.Run(WorkAsync);

            await Task.Delay(10);
            IsResourceAvailable = false;

            await Task.Delay(100);
            IsResourceAvailable = true;
            WaitResourceTokenSource.Cancel();

            Console.WriteLine("End Work");
        }

        public static async Task WorkAsync()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Begin Work");
            while (true)
            {
                if (!IsResourceAvailable)
                    await WaitResource();

                for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    Method();
                }
            }
        }

        private static async Task WaitResource()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wait");
            try
            {
                WaitResourceTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, WaitResourceTokenSource.Token);
            }
            catch
            {
                // ignored
            }
            Console.WriteLine("End Wait");
        }

        private static void Method()
        {
            var sum = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                sum++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Текущие способы похожи на костыли` > `async void`...

Comment: Проблема этого кода в том что в консоль не выводится сообщение "Press AnyKey to end".
При отладке обнаружил что при отмене ожидания происходит возобновление асинхронного метода, которое застревает в бесконечном цикле.

Comment: удалось разобраться?

Comment: @aepot, нет, вариант с поллингом мне не подходит, потому что я как раз стараюсь отказаться от него. Пока что остановился на ```await Task.Delay(1);```.

Comment: А у вас нет других вариантов, либо поллинг, либо блокировка потока ожиданием клавиши. Ну как знаете, удаляю ответ.

Comment: Проблема блокировки ожиданием клавиши в том, что не разблокировать поток не нажав клавишу, хотя-бы виртуально. Кстати, а вак вы поняли, что `Console.KeyAvailable` вам не походит?

Comment: Кстати, ваш пример из вопроса, который вы туда дописали, не рабочий, ваш токен отмены ничего не отменяет. Ваш `Method()` досчитает до конца, что бы вы не делали. А следовательно смысла 0 во всем этом. Представьте, что `Method()` работает 10 секунд. Засуньте туда паузы, выведите конечную сумму в консоль в конце концов. Что отменять то собрались? Вопрос же про отмену был? Создайте рабочий пример сначала, типа того что я вам написал, но на этот раз сами. Попробуйте реально отменить что-то, а не фейково.

Comment: Представьте операцию на 10 секунд, если вы не вызвали отмену, то операция завершилась успешно. Если вызвали - завершилась сразу как вызвали. В этом и есть смысл токена отмены. И да `CancellationTokenSource` - `IDisposable` и содержит неуправляемые ресурсы: [Использование объектов, реализующих IDisposable](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects)

Comment: @aepot, Мне необходимо отменить бесконечное ожидание ресурса ```await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, WaitResourceTokenSource.Token);```, а метод WorkAsync должен продолжить свою работу. Проблема в том что поток, который прерывает ожидание, застревает в методе WorkAsync, а мне необходимо чтоб он разблокировал спящий поток, после чего продолжил бы выполнение.

Comment: Вы пока не поняли, как это работает, несмотря на то что я вам показывал. Вы говорите о блокировке потока, но ваш вопрос про асинхронное программирование, где блокировка потока - сама по себе нонсенс. Еще раз, вот [документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async), читайте, там есть ссылки на другие документы, их тоже читайте.